# Multi Fragments with canGoBack crash on click

Tags: android, fragment

I have a problem with two different fragments that contain two different web views. I have three activities, two for the fragment (FragmentTwo.java and FragmentThree.java) and one for the Activity (MainActivity.Java).

In [MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdFb3.jpg):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(FragmentTwo.canGoBack()){
        FragmentTwo.goBack();
    }
    else if(FragmentThree.canGoBack()){
        FragmentThree.goBack();
    }

    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

In [fragment activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynclp.jpg):

```
    public static boolean canGoBack(){
    return myWebView.canGoBack();
}

public static void goBack(){
    myWebView.goBack();
}
```

When I click on back button the app crashes. How I can solve this problem?

```
08-28 12:53:33.886: E/InputEventSender(23075): Exception dispatching finished signal.
08-28 12:53:33.886: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at com.alessandroCeccon.mobilesystem.FragmentTwo.canGoBack(FragmentTwo.java:61)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at com.alessandroCeccon.mobilesystem.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:166)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2648)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2225)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3932)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3592)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3649)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3625)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2213)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1854)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1845)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2190)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
08-28 12:53:33.891: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23075):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
08-28 12:53:33.891: D/AndroidRuntime(23075): Shutting down VM
08-28 12:53:33.891: D/AndroidRuntime(23075): --------- beginning of crash
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): Process: com.alessandroCeccon.mobilesystem, PID: 23075
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.alessandroCeccon.mobilesystem.FragmentTwo.canGoBack(FragmentTwo.java:61)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.alessandroCeccon.mobilesystem.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:166)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2453)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2648)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2704)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2225)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3932)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3592)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3649)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3463)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3482)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3625)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2213)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1854)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1845)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2190)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:195)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
08-28 12:53:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

(reference: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLWWD.jpg),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2fx.jpg),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiw1n.jpg),[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2p56.jpg),[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9u8L.jpg),[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PoRi.jpg),[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySmrb.jpg),[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiWVi.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

First Of all you are getting Null pointer exception

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference.
```

which means you need to initialise the object. in your case its the webview.

and it looks like you are trying to access webview object of FragmentActivity(i.e FragmentTwo.java) from MainActivity.Java on onBackPressed(), which will not work.

Try Writing OnBackPress Code inside your FragmentActivity. cheers

Comment: If i try to write it in the FragmentActivity it doesn't accept the "Else" text. "The method  is undefined for the type Fragment". @Jolson

Comment: @Alessandro Ceccon. your Question is wrong i suppose. FragmentTwo.java is not FragmentActivty, you must have extended it to Fragment. thats why you getting that "method is undefined error for ELSE. jus check the initialisation of webView Object

Comment: This is the top of my FragmentTwo.java:                                                       public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
....

 private static WebView myWebView;          @Jolson

Comment: Please Paste Your FragmentTwo.Java code in your question.

Comment: When i click the back button the app crash with the log i post before. @jolson

Answer (score 0):

As the error log stated, the reason is because `myWebView` is null.

The reason might vary depends on how you declare `myWebView`, but it's probably because you're follow this kind of online tutorial code snippet:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

So your code might end up that:

```
public static WebView myWebView; 

public View onCreateView(...) {
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    ...
}

public static boolean canGoBack() {
    return myWebView.canGoBack();
}

public static void goBack() { 
     myWebView.goBack();
}
```

This was wrong because `myWebView` is still null due to `myWebView` defined inside `onCreateView()` has been "redeclared" by prefix `WebView`, which this definition only persists within the scope of `onCreateView()`.

The solution is remove the prefix `WebView`, e.g.:

```
myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```